# Keyword search of Existing Registered Domains?

Tags: search, domains

I want to be able to search for domains by keyword.  I've been looking for tools to do this of course and all that ever pops up are tools to help you register a domain and give you possible suggestions if that one is taken.
That is no help.

Let's say for example I want to find domains registered with the word "platypus" in them.  Assuming there were only 5 sites registered with that word in it then finding all of these should come up.

electric-platypus.co.uk

platypus.com

platypushosting.com

platypusfacts.net

charityplatypus.org

Now what I was trying to do, as I couldn't find anything past endless domain registration sites, was get Google to return only domains it had crawled with certain keywords in the domain itself (not the URL).  I'm still working towards this but if there's a surfire way to do it, or a service which provides that capability (we'd pay for it), I'd appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single canonical list of domain names.

Some TLDs offer paid access to their lists:  (taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307553/possible-to-download-entire-whois-database-list-of-registered-domains))

> For .com and .net, Verisign provides the [TLD Zone Access Program](http://www.verisign.com/information-services/naming-services/com-net-registry/page_001052.html) where you can apply for download access to the zone files. Other registries usually provide similar services.
>
> Here is a list for some other TLDs (though I haven't tried to apply for any of these):
>
> - .org: http://www.pir.org/index.php?db=content/Website&tbl=Registrars&id=7
> - .biz: https://www.neulevel.biz/zonefile/
> - .info: http://www.afilias.info/faqs/for_registrars/general_registrar
> - .name: http://gnr.name/zone-file-access.html
> - .coop: http://www.nic.coop/agreements.aspx
> - .pro: http://www.registrypro.pro
> - .mobi: http://mtld.mobi/domain/zonefile

Comment: Thanks.  That's specifically why we were trying to extract this through Google seeing as it likely even crawls the domains for sale sites.  It ought to have at least seen a domain even if it ends up in a blocking robots.txt file.

Comment: I would not expect Google to reliably index parked domains. They likely treat them as duplicate content and filter them out.